# SwiftUI Http POST mysql

Tags: php, swiftui, http-post

I'm building an CRUD app with SwiftUI. Reading from the mysql database is working. But when I try to create a record I get an empty record in my database. If I print out the parameters in Xcode I'm sending to the database I see this result: ["title": "Test 4", "post": "This is test 4"]. In my php script I use this POST code:

```
$title    = $_POST['title'];
$post    = $_POST['post'];
```

In Xcode I use this code to get the value from the textfields:

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = ["title": title, "post": post]
```

And this code to use it in a Http POST:

```
 let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)
 var request = URLRequest(url: url)
 request.httpMethod = "POST"
 request.httpBody = data
 request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

I can find info about this for swift and build an app, but it doesn't work in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are sending JSON but on the PHP side expecting form parameters. You'll need to change your PHP to get the json from the body and parse it. A very basic example below:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$title = $json->title;
$post = $json->post;
```

Comment: Thanks! I know I was missing something simple.